# Compute the gravitational force between two vertical rods

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, newtonian-gravity

My AP physics teacher posed this problem at the end of his lecture today and I want to be sure my physical set up is correct (I've already done the math, but just double checking!). The situation is this: two vertical rods of heights $a$ and $b$ (and masses $M_1$ and $M_2$, respectively) are separated by a distance $d$. Compute the net gravitational attraction between the rods. My main set of is based on the figure below. [image]Note, by the method in which I've set it up, $$r=\sqrt{d^2+(x-y)^2}, $$ thus $$\vec{F}_G=\int_0^b\int_0^a\frac{GdM_1dM_2}{d^2+(x-y)^2}.$$ $dM_1=\frac{M_1}{a}dx$ and $dM_2=\frac{M_2}{b}dy.$ Consequently, $$\vec{F}_G=\int_0^b\int_0^a\frac{GM_1M_2}{ab(d^2+(x-y)^2)} dxdy= \frac{GM_1M_2}{ab}\int_0^b\int_0^a\frac{dxdy}{d^2+(x-y)^2}. $$ I've gone through the math and the solution is anything but pretty. But is this initial set up (the physics portion of the problem) correct?

Comment: why not finding the center of mass of each rod and then find out the gravitational force

Comment: @Anni - As I recall, reducing a gravitational interaction between two objects to just the interaction between their total masses located at their respective center of masses only works if both objects are spheres. For all other geometries, you have to break the objects into little itty-bitty pieces and integrate over all of the pairs of pieces to find the net force as Matthew Fox is attempting.

Comment: @Matthew Fox: Your setup looks good as far as I can tell EXCEPT for the fact that it appears that you switched from having the correct denominator of d^2+(x-y)^2 to the incorrect denominator of d^2-(x-y)^2 starting with the 3rd equation of your derivation.

Comment: Ah yes, that was just a typing error on my part. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Matthew Fox - Oh, wait! I forgot something and so did you: The force F is a vector. You actually have to set the problem up so that you're calculating both the x- and y-components of F. As for the integral that you set up, it won't give the correct total force even if you set a=b so that there is no force in the y-direction but only the x-direction. You simply summed up over all of the individual forces regardless of the directions of the individual force vectors. You need to break down the individual forces into the x- and y- components.